# Does not conform to protocol hashable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create view model according to JSON response but getting bellow error.

[image]

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
    
public class DeclarationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var description: [DeclarationListViewModel]?
    init() {
        self.description = [DeclarationListViewModel]()
    }
    init(shortDescription: [DeclarationListViewModel]?) {
        self.description = shortDescription
    }
}
    
public class DeclarationListViewModel: ObservableObject, Hashable {
    @Published var yesNo: Bool?
    @Published var title: String?
}
```

trying to use result in foreach

[image]

Thank you for help.
Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: What is the point of an optional Boolean? Probably both of those properties should be non-optional.

Comment: Click on the fix button and setup the hash method

Comment: @loremipsum i did but its not what i am looking for..its not working

Comment: @Paulw11 yes agree with you

Comment: Look at the documentation you are missing func hash and == https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

Comment: Thanks but not sure why its asking for hashable

Comment: the error is not asking for hashable, it is asking for Equatable. Just remove the hashable from DeclarationListViewModel

Comment: Why is DeclarationListViewModel a class and why is it conforming to ObservableObject? It looks more like a model so why not make it a struct?

Comment: hashable is require as I am using description in foreach.  "Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that "DeclarationListViewModel' conform to 'Hashable'"

Comment: @Rahul using `description` name for a collection is definitely misleading. Note that you should only use `description` when conforming to `CustomStringConvertible`

Comment: Btw description is not a static property. You should iterate an instance of DeclarationViewModel. I would also iterate the "description" indices instead.

Answer (score 26):

Remove the `import SwiftUI` try not to use it in your ViewModels, unless really necessary. Also remove `Hashable` from your class declaration and outside of it create an extension like this for example:

```
extension DeclarationListViewModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var identifier: String {
        return UUID().uuidString
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        return hasher.combine(identifier)
    }
    
    public static func == (lhs: DeclarationListViewModel, rhs: DeclarationListViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

Also remember that `structs` exists, they are great for defining your models.

One more thing, maybe instead of having an optional boolean, why not initialize it with false and in your view or viewmodel, wherever you call it first, set it to true if that's the case.

Comment: OberservableObjects have to be classes.

Comment: Why did you use `var identifier: String { ... }`  instead of `let id = UUID()`?

Comment: Could you add reasoning behind why you should split the `Hashable` declaration out to an extension? Is it because it's a "Swifty" thing to do? Or is there another reason other than "this is the way we organize code in swift"?

Answer (score 9):

The compiler is simply telling you that by saying

", Hashable" in your class declaration, you are promising to adhere to the rules of protocol Hashable. Additionally Hashable inherits from protocol Equatable. To adhere to the rules of Hashable you are also saying you agree to the rules of Equatable. The rules of protocols are simply a list of functions that you promise to implement and or variables you promise to have.

In your case you need this requirement for protocol equatable:
[image]

And you need to fulfill this promise for protocol Hashable:

[image]

You can find this type of information by looking carefully through the documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

In your case you need to add two methods inside of DeclarationListViewModel

extension DeclarationListViewModel {
static func ==(lhs: DeclarationListViewModel, rhs: DeclarationListViewModel) {

```
    return lhs.yesNo == rhs.yesNo &&
           lhs.title == rhs.title
}
```

}

and to be Hashable

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(yesNo)
    hasher.combine(title)
}
```

Comment: Great refresher, thanks!